# Anoche actualice mi sdk de flutter a 1.17.3 y el showDatePicker me lo cambio rotundamente

Tags: flutter, datepicker

tengo un problemilla , anoche actualice mi sdk de flutter a la version 1.17.3 y ahora el showDatePicker me muestra con el tema por defecto que siempre viene flutter al crear un proyecto es decir( ese color celeste ) y tambien en ingles, pero antes de actualizarlo el sdk todo estaba bien me lo mostraba en español y puej con el tema que yo queria (que era color rojiso) no se que paso yo no cambie nada de mi codigo aqui le muestro mi codigo del showDatePicker que tengo:

```
   void _mostrarDate(BuildContext context) {
      final provedorDeBloc = Provider.of(context);
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     showDatePicker(
      locale: Locale('es'),
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(1900,0),
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: new DateTime(2101),
      builder: ( BuildContext contexto , Widget child ) {
          return Theme(
              data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                 buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
                      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
                    ),
                primaryColor: Colores.COLOR_ROJISO_TEXTO_LOYALTY,//Head background
                accentColor: Colores.COLOR_ROJISO_TEXTO_LOYALTY//selection color
                //dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,//Background color
                ),     
                child: child,
          );
      }
    ).then( (DateTime fecha){
         if( fecha != null ){
              String valor =  dateFormat.format(fecha);
              provedorDeBloc.addDataToStreamFechaNac(valor);
              ///esto se hara solo para mostrar en la vista pero al servidor se manda otro
              DateFormat formaToVisual = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
              String formatoVisualString = formaToVisual.format(fecha);
              this.controladorTextEditingFechaNac.text = formatoVisualString;
              
         }

    } );
    }
```

Como ven el tema solo especifico para el calendario no funciona aun y aqui le muestro el tema que tengo en el main para todo el proyecto y tambien lo del idioma:

esto es en el archivo main.dart

```
 MaterialApp(

           localizationsDelegates: [
       // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en'), // English
          const Locale('es'), // Hebrew
          
        ],


       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       title: 'Loyalty Flutter Base',
       theme: ThemeData(
           primaryColor: Colores.COLOR_ROJISO_TEXTO_LOYALTY,
           secondaryHeaderColor: Colores.COLOR_ROJISO_TEXTO_LOYALTY,
           
       ),
       initialRoute: preferencias.devolverValor(Constantes.last_page, 
       WelcomePage.nameOfPage),
       routes: obtenerRutas(),
    ),
```

entonces el tema que yo le estoy poniendo es un color rojiso mas o menos.
Gracias por su ayuda :).
Bueno cualquier cosa q necesiten de mi codigo o interfaz puedo agregarlas gracias.

Comment: revisa el código fuente dentro de `showDatePicker` , para que veas que tema coge y también podrías revisar si tiene algún parámetro de `locale` para el idioma

Comment: Gracias diegoVeloper